# comm command output in bash versus zsh

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh, array

In the process of transitioning from `bash` to `zsh`. I am comparing the contents of two folders, and echo the files that are common:

```
common_files=$(comm -12 <(ls -p "$folder1") <(ls -p "$folder2"))
  for f in ${common_files[@]}; do
  echo "pass:"
  echo "$f"
done
```

While on `bash` I get an array with separate entries:

```
pass:
file1
pass:
file2
pass:
file3
```

the output on `zsh` shows all elements are "conflated" into a single array entry:

```
pass:
file1
file2
file3
```

How can I get the same behavior in `zsh` as originally? Thank you.

Comment: `common_files` is not an array. Because of this `${common_files[@]}` is like `$common_files`. Unquoted `$common_files` [undergoes word splitting and filename generation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) in Bash, this is hardly ever a good thing. Zsh fixes this and treats unquoted `$common_files` like `"$common_files"`. And you're [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place. Do you *really* want to get the same flawed behavior in `zsh`?

Comment: Points taken. I knew parsing the output of `ls` would be frowned upon (and rightly so), except all the reasons for which this fails in practice do not apply to this set of files (including the paths). Dully noted re: word splitting not happening in in `zsh`. That's it, thank you.

Comment: No time for high quality answer now, sorry. Start with `IFS=$'\n'; common_files=($(comm -12 <(ls -p "$folder1") <(ls -p "$folder2")))` to build a real array. Restore the default `IFS` if needed. Then `for f in "${common_files[@]}"; do`.

Comment: Thanks! If you feel, later inclined to, make your comment into an answer and I'll mark it as such. In the mean time, I'll write a higher quality solution to my problem, too :).

Comment: I will pass. [You write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). No need to mention me in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it properly in Zsh, with arrays:

```sh
common-files() {
  file-names $1 && local -a files_a=( $reply )
  file-names $2 && local -a files_b=( $reply )

  # `:*`: Keep only the items common to both. 
  # `(F)`: Join the items with newlines.
  print ${(F)files_a:*files_b}
}

file-names() {
  # `.`: Match only files (not dirs).
  # `D`: Include dotfiles.
  local -a paths=( $1/*(#q.D) )

  # `:t`: Keep only the name ("tail") of each file, not its whole path.
  reply=( $paths:t )
}
```